# Dissolving points with multiple attributes in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dissolve

I have a series of GPS points with one ID (Track 1, Track 2, Track 3...) but they also have different fields like elevation.

I want to dissolve these GPS points using the ID, retain only 1 point per ID, and select the point with highest values, in this case, the elevation.

[image: sample path]

This can be done in ArcGIS 10.3 using Productive Planning Tool but I only have ArcGIS 10.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use Dissolve to find the highest elevation using Field Statistics
- Join the (temporary) data with the original data by (Track)ID; make sure to copy your input data and set it as the input table, as to not overwrite your original dataset
- Use Select to match the MAX_elevation attribute with the original elevation attribute
- (Optional) delete the created fields by Dissolve and Join from the output

I've created a small feature class based on your information, which looks like this:

[image: InputData]

After the steps explained above, the result is this:

[image: OutputData]

The complete model and settings look like this and should be enough information for you to recreate the same result:

[image: ModelForUniqueHighestValue]

Comment: Can you show what's inside Join Field and Select Tool?

Comment: @user2543 I've added more information, I noticed that it was not possible to not alter the original dataset without using Copy Features, maybe this was what was preventing you from getting the same result?